# PHP: Assigning of NULL to variable, TRUE or FALSE ? What is NULL?

Tags: php, null

In PHP:

```
$var = NULL;
```

What happened here? Was NULL assigned to $var, or was $var created with unknown value because assigning NULL does nothing?

Consider a for-loop

```
$arr=array();
for($i=0;$arr[$i]=NULL;$i++){}
```

that does break on this condition. This must mean that assigning of NULL is evaluated to FALSE, which means that assignment never took place and the value of $arr[0] is undetermined. A var_dump would simply give

```
array(1) { [0]=> NULL }
```

but I have never been sure what to make of that. From my reasoning with the for-loop above I would assume that NULL in PHP means "undetermined", but until now I have always believed that NULL is a type that can be assigned. If NULL could actually be assigned, then the for-loop should not break as the assigning of NULL is TRUE.

Reading http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php it seems that NULL is somehow determined because a strict comparison of NULL and array() is FALSE, which is fine, but a loose comparison is TRUE. To me, this implies that NULL actually is something rather than undetermined.

It seems to me that NULL is not entirely consistent.

MY QUESTION FOR YOU: What is wrong with my logic?

Comment: I'm not sure what's unclear. __1:__ assignment `=` operator will return result of expression that was assigned to variable __after execution__. So that's why you'll get your element in an array. __2:__ second expression in `for` loop is always treated as boolean expression, therefore, it's result will be checked against `true` according to PHP's type juggling. That's why you'll get that `for` condition will break (true in comparison to null will give false).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> $var = NULL;
> ```
>
> What happened here?

Simple: the value `null` was assigned to `$var`.

Yes, `null` is a value. A regular, normal value. `null` is not a boolean, not a number, not anything else. `null` is of type `null`, which can only take one possible value: `null`. `null` is typically used as a placeholder value to signify "no value". But `null` is just a perfectly normal value and type in itself. Nothing to see here, move along.

> ```
> for ($i = 0; $arr[$i] = NULL; $i++) { }
> ```

Here `null` is assigned to `$arr[$i]` on the first iteration. The assignment expression itself then returns the assigned value, i.e. `($arr[$i] = NULL)` evaluates to the value `null`. The `for` loop then evaluates this `null` to decide whether it should continue or not, and since `null` is regarded as equal to `false`, it stops. The result of this loop is:

> ```
> array(1) { [0]=> NULL }
> ```

I.e. an array whose first and only index is the value `null`. Nothing more, nothing less.

> If NULL could actually be assigned, then the for-loop should not break
>   as the assigning of NULL is TRUE.

That's your only misunderstanding here. The result of an assignment expression is **the assigned value**. Not `true`. That's why this works:

```
$a = $b = $c;
```

`$a` is assigned the result of `$b = $c`, which is `$c`.

In all these examples you could replace `null` with `false` for the exact same effect.

Comment: Thanks! I think the thing that really made me confused was what the PHP documentation says about for-loops: "In the beginning of each iteration, expr2 is evaluated. If it evaluates to TRUE, the loop continues". I always assumed that it is the success of an assignment that makes the evaluation TRUE, but you're saying that as long as the value to be assigned evaluates to TRUE, the expression is TRUE (assuming the rest of the expression is valid PHP). That makes perfect sense.

Comment: Yep, it's all about *expressions*. You can have a ridiculously long, complex, nested *expression* in there. The `for` loop only cares about what the end result evaluates to, it doesn't have any specific preferences for what kind of expression you give it.