# difference between Null and False

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i watching **tutorial** about developing guestbook with **php**

this is the code that get the message with the id

```
public function GetMessage($id)
{
    //Database
    $id = (int)$id;
    $gb_host     = 'localhost' ; 
    $gb_dbname   = 'guestbook' ; 
    $gb_username = 'root';
    $gb_password = '' ;

    $connection  = mysqli_connect($gb_host , $gb_username , $gb_password,$gb_dbname);

    $querycheck = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM `messages` WHERE `id` = $id");
    if($querycheck)
    {
        $message  = mysqli_fetch_assoc($querycheck); 

        return $message;
    }
    else
    {
        mysqli_close($connection);
        return NULL;
    }
    mysqli_close($connection);      
}
```

why in else statment we return NULL instead of False

what's the difference between Null and False ?

Comment: in DB terms, `null` is unknown/undefined. `false` is a known/defined value.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: Assigning of NULL to variable, TRUE or FALSE ? What is NULL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23674643/php-assigning-of-null-to-variable-true-or-false-what-is-null)

Comment: @Marc B can i ask you for more clarification ...  False can we use it if he didn't found the row in DB ?

Comment: `$message` will already be false if there's no matching rows in the db. can't fetch anything from an empty result set.

Comment: ok if it'll be false why in else statement he close the connection and return NULL why he didn't leave it as false

Comment: it tried to call the function from the class & typed return false ....                                                        $message = $gb ->GetMessage($id);                                                                 ...   it was the same result (it didn't show anything when you type wrong id )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type.

False is boolean and null is a value.

So :

```
$test = false;
if($test === false) {
 //correct
}

$test = null;
if ($test === false) {
 //incorrect
} else if ($test === null) {
 //correct
}

$test = false;
if(!$test) { 
    //correct
}

$test = null;

if(!$test) {
    //correct
}
```

More precision in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php)

Comment: can you explain  my code ? why he typed NULL instead of false .. why in else statement he close the connection and return NULL why he didn't leave it as false

Comment: Because the value is not found. Not finding anything should be NULL.

Comment: If is not found and you return false. It's correct syntax.

Comment: You can use both. It's as you like.

Comment: are you sure :D that made me confused yesterday :D

Comment: Yes, its your choice to choose what's you return. Personally I prefer return false in a function and set null to a value.

Comment: even if it's false or Null and when i call the function  will be the same right ? so i can use anything it won't be problem

Comment: Exacltly. Just depend on what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Imho in this case and **null** and **false** are incorrect, because method should return one type of data!

In our method it should be array not special type (null) or boolean,
and it will be easy to use this method elsewhere, because everytime we know that we works with array, and we don't have write something like this:

```
$messages = $dao->GetMessage(27);
if (is_array($messages)) {
    // ...
}
if (is_null($messages)) {
    $messages = []; // because wihout it foreach will down
}
foreach ($messages as $message) {
    // ...
}
```

And as for me it's pretty straightforward:

if we have data at db we'll receive not empty array,

if we don't have data at db - we'll receive empty array.

It's obviously!

Comment: bro i need to understand the code of the tutorial and know why NULL instead of false